# WP-navi plugin and post sorted alphabetically

Tags: pages, navigation

I've got an issue with using the WP-Navi plugin and posts sorted alphabetically.  The first page of posts (5 - set in the plugin settings) appearing properly, but when one navigates to subsequent pages, I lose that sort.  In fact, I can't tell how the posts are being sorted - it appears to be random.

The plugin's author has a description of this problem, but says that it's fixed in the plugin version that I have and I can't figure out where in the plugin code to verify.  Should I abandon the plugin and try to code into the template or functions file?

Can anyone help?

Comment: Add a link to the plugin. There are so many similar named plugins – we cannot know which one you use.

Comment: Thank you!  Here is the link to the plugin:  http://webdevstudios.com/plugin/custom-post-type-ui/

Comment: That’s not a WP-Navi plugin, is it? Now I’m confused.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me with this one.  I'm sorry that I had provided the incorrect link - way too tired at that point.  I eventually figured it out on my own and then had trouble getting back into this site to acknowledge your effort on my behalf.  All is good now - thanks again~

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer and **mark it as answer**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching to a new navigation plugin solved this problem!

`http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-paginate/`